# How to use javascript to assign classes to divs on a sequential basis?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've tried searching for an answer, but without joy - I'm new to JS (as in started learning last week), and I've hit a problem that I don't even know where to look to start solving.

I have a `div` with the id `container`, inside that div are lots of little divs with the class `item`. I want to give those `.item`s the additional classes of `tile1` for the first div, `tile2` for the second, `tile3` for the third, `tile4` for the fourth, then going back to `tile1` for the fifth, `tile2` for the sixth etc.

The amount of `.tile`s in the `#container` will be dynamically generated, possibly with waypoints using infinite scroll, which makes me want to use javascript to do this rather than manually type these classes in.

Can anyone give me some pointers?

Thanks!

Comment: Uh... why? The psuedo-class `:nth-child(4n+1)` will get the first, fifth, ninth... You can also do `4n+2`, `4n+3` and `4n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.addClass()` method and modulus operator:

```
$('#container .item').addClass(function(i) { 
    return 'tile' + (i % 4 + 1);
});
```

http://jsbin.com/evuFOqUd/3/edit

Or in case that you are not using jQuery:

```
[].forEach.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('#container .item'), 
  function(el, i) {
    el.classList.add('tile' + (i % 4 + 1));
  }
);
```

Which only works in modern browsers.

Answer (score 1):

#### [Here's a jsbin demo](http://jsbin.com/irEdAbAs/2)

---

jQuery [.each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) is your friend

```
$("#container .item").each(function(idx, elem) {
  $(elem).addClass("tile" + (idx + 1));
});
```

---

EDIT

I did not see that you wanted the tile numbers to wrap

```
$("#container .item").each(function(idx, elem) {
  $(elem).addClass("tile" + (idx % 4 + 1));
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Despite the fact that I can see it work in your JSbin, for some reason it won't work for me in my own code - probably because of myu inexperience. I've tried putting $(document).ready (function() { [your code] )} and still no luck.

Comment: @Wilf, not sure what to tell you there. You could have other JavaScript errors on the page? Perhaps post another question once you identify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A non-jQuery approach (pardon the pseudo-code):

```
var breakAfter = 4; // Reset iterator after reaching 5 runs
var iterator = 0;
var elementList = document.querySelector(".myk00lElementClass"); // Your DOM nodes
for (element in elementList) { 

    element.classList.add('dynamicClass_' + iterator);

    // Reset dynamic class number if we have reached arbitrary length above
    if (iterator >= breakAfter) {
        iterator = 0;

    // Or, keep on truckin'
    } else {
        iterator++;
    }
}
```